# How to identify Keyframes in the Timeline

Tags: keyframes, graph-editor, timeline

I inserted Keyframes for both Location, Rotation and Scale in the time line, in the exact same spot.

It's easier to differentiate what Keyframe is for what location or rotation in the Graph Editor as it is listed on the left side, but I can't tell what exact Keyframes I'm looking at under the Timeline; is it the location Keyframes or the rotation. I cannot tell.

How do I identify what Keyframe Is visible?

I want to set a bezier interpolation on the location Keyframes, but looking in the Timeline, I can't tell if it's the location, rotation or scale Keyframes.

Comment: You can see what kind of track it is in the Timeline as well, you need to unfold the left panel

Comment: I'm just learning about this. Didn't know it was in the tiny left arrow on the side of the timeline. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the tracks in the *Timeline* as well, click on the small arrow on the left to unfold the panel:

[image]